# Outputting Ruby indexes

Tags: ruby, indexing

I have a quick and likely simple question that I couldn't find the answer to. It's probably because I'm not really sure how to ask the question properly but here goes:

```
def test(num)
  num_s = num.to_s
  num_s.each_char do |number|
    p num_s.index(number)
  end
end

test(232435)
```

output is:
0
1
0
3
1
5

output I expected:
0
1
2
3
4
5

Why isn't the output consecutive indexes?

Comment: the `index` method returns the **first** occurrance. Since, for example, value 2 is in both position 0 and 2, it shows up at 0 twice in the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So if I wanted to list each of the indexes of the number I wouldn't want to use the index method but but something else.  Could somone show me a better way to get my expected output?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? `'what_for?'.each_char.with_index { |_, i| print i }` returns `012345678`

Comment: @Brando you usually `.with_index`

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted- your help is huge!  .with_index is what I was looking for.  I had seen it before but never put it into practice.

Comment: Just to know: arrays have special method `each_with_index`

Comment: If your question is really solved, choose the answer you like and accept it

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Sring#index` returns the index of the **first** occurrence of the given substring.

You can [read it here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-index).

```
test(232435)
```

`"2"` firstly appears at index `0`

`"3"` firstly appears at index `1`

`"2"` firstly appears at index `0`

`"4"` firstly appears at index `3`

`"3"` firstly appears at index `1`

`"5"` firstly appears at index `5`

> output I expected: 0 1 2 3 4 5

You can get it by your method only if you have different digits in `num`.

For example `123456` or `809163`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your follow-up question:

```rb
def test(num)
  num_s = num.to_s
  num_s.each_char.with_index do |number, index| # notice the difference here
    p index
  end
end

test(232435)

# => 0 
# => 1 
# => 2 
# => ...etc
```

From here you can go on to also using that `number` param, say if you want to output something a bit more informative you could try:

```rb
def test(num)
  num_s = num.to_s
  num_s.each_char.with_index do |number, index|
    p "Number #{number} is at index #{index}"
  end
end

test(232435)

# => "Number 2 is at index 0"
# => "Number 3 is at index 1"
# => ...etc
```

If you want to do the same thing but you have an array instead of a string, use `.each_with_index` instead of `.each_char.with_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows. To simplify, I've made the method argument a string rather than an integer that is immediately converted to a string.

```
def test(num)
  start_index = Hash.new(0)
  num.each_char do |digit|           
    i = num.index(digit, start_index[digit])
    puts "index for #{digit} is #{i}"
    start_index[digit] = i + 1
  end 
end

test("232435")
index for 2 is 0
index for 3 is 1
index for 2 is 2
index for 4 is 3
index for 3 is 4
index for 5 is 5
```

This works because the second argument of [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-index) specifies the index *offset* at which the search is to begin.

The problem is that this method is useless. It would be simpler to write the following.

```
def test(num)
  num.each_char.with_index { |digit,i| puts "index for #{digit} is #{i}" }
end

test("232435")
index for 2 is 0
index for 3 is 1
index for 2 is 2
index for 4 is 3
index for 3 is 4
index for 5 is 5
```

One could add arguments to the method that are digits whose indices in the first argument are to be determined.

```
def test(num, *args)
  start_index = Hash.new(0)
  args.each do |digit|
    i = num.index(digit, start_index[digit])
    puts "index for #{digit} is #{i}"
    start_index[digit] = i + 1
  end
end

test("232435", "3", "4", "2", "3", "2")
index for 3 is 1
index for 4 is 3
index for 2 is 0
index for 3 is 4
index for 2 is 2
```

If I were to add a last line `start_index` to this method the return value would be

```
{"3"=>5, "4"=>4, "2"=>3}
```

meaning that the search for the next `"3"` is to begin at offset `5`, and so on.

Naturally, additional code would be needed to check that an argument is a digit and a digit of the string, that the number of arguments that are the same digit does not exceed the number of that digit in the string, and so on.

Comment: I feel that I massively misunderstand the question, because all the answers seem much too complex to me. The output the OP wants seems completely independent from the content of the string. It is just `0...num_s.size`. The size of the decimal representation of a number, is just log10 of that number, so not only do the contents of the string not matter, it doesn't even matter what the number is, only what order of magnitude, so the output the OP wants is just `(0...(Math.log(num, 10) + 1).floor)`. There is no need to iterate at all, it's a O(1) solution (except for the printing, of course).

Comment: Well, it's O(whatever the complexity of `Math.log` is), to be pedantic.

Comment: @Jörg, I cannot disagree and admit to answering a question that was not asked, namely, my second method `test`, which conceivably might be of use to someone in some applications. If I were more disciplined I wouldn't do that (and generally don't): answer questions that aren't asked. On the other hand, I and perhaps others might learn something useful from such wayward behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For the output you want, it is irrelevant what the content of the string is. *Every string* (of the same length) will have the exact same output. Your entire method only depends on the length on the string and has nothing to to do with the indices of the characters at all. It's literally just:

```
0...num_s.size
```

Like this:

```
def test(num)
  num_s = num.to_s
  (0...num_s.size).map(&method(:puts))
end

test(232435)
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

But, the length of the decimal representation of a number is just the 10-base logarithm of the number:

```
def test(num)
  length = (Math.log(num, 10) + 1).floor
  (0...length).map(&method(:puts))
end

test(232435)
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

So, not only does this not have anything to do with the contents of the string, it doesn't even have anything to do with what the actual number is, the output will always be the same for any number with the same amount of decimal places, i.e. any number from 100000..999999 will yield the same result.